# Sampling and/or asymptotic distribution of a function

Tags: statistics, research, returns, mathematics

Assume we have the following function:

$$f(p) = \frac{1}{(1-p)d}\ln\left(\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\left[\frac{1+X_t}{1+Y_t} \right]^{1-p} \right)$$

where

$d$ is a constant

$T$ is a constant

$X_t$ for $t = 1, 2, \cdots, T$ are random variables (it is actually the portfolio's annualized rate of return at time $t$)

$Y_t$ for $t = 1, 2, \cdots, T$ are random variables (it is actually the risk-free rate at time $t$)

$p$ is defined such that it is value that satisfies $f(p) = 0$

What is the sampling and/or asymptotic distribution for the statistic $p$?

**By sampling distribution I mean the following:**

The solution to $f(p) = 0$ doesn't have a closed-form solution, but it is obvious that the resulting value of $p$ depends on $X_t$ and $Y_t$, so $p$ can be treated as a random variable that depends on the random variables $X_t$ and $Y_t$. Then for every (fixed) $T$ observations of $X_t$ and $Y_t$, we have a corresponding value $p$ that satisfies $f(p) = 0$, what is the sampling distribution of $p$?

**By asymptotic distribution I mean the following:**

Similar to above, now assume $T$ isn't fixed, then clearly the solution $p$ to $f(p)=0$ implicitly depends on $T$, then what is the asymptotic distribution of $p$ as $T \rightarrow \infty$?

---

Assume you are allowed the following assumptions to achieve the above:

1) You can make any distributional assumptions regarding $X_t$ and $Y_t$, e.g., $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are independent from each other, also $X_t$, $Y_t$ for $t = 1, 2, \cdots, T$ are independently and identically distributed.

2) Rather than making distributional assumptions about $X_t$ and $Y_t$, assume you can make some assumptions about the processes $\{X_t\}$ and $\{Y_t\}$, e.g., both processes are stationary (or weakly stationary) etc.

3) Any assumption you see fit to yield a solution.

---

This is what I've tried so far.

If we let $Z_t = \frac {1 + X_t} {1 + Y_t}$, then we have $\displaystyle f(p) = \frac {1} {(1 - p)d} \ln\left(\frac {1} {T} \sum_{t=1}^T Z_t^{1-p} \right)$. Setting this equation to $0$ and rearranging, we have:
$$\sum_{t=1}^T Z_t^{1-p} = T$$

The my question becomes:

1) Sampling distribution: For a fixed $T$, what is the distribution of $p$?

2) Asymptotic distribution: For $T \rightarrow \infty$, what is the distribution of $p$?

Comment: So basically you are looking for a random variable $p$ that will give you the following result $\sum_{t=1}^T Z_t(\omega)^{1-p(\omega)}=T$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$ ?

Comment: could $p$ be a vector of length $T$ ?

Comment: also is the functional form of $f(p)$ mandatory or could one add some weights ?

Comment: @Probilitator Apologies for the late reply, I've been overseas (and still am, but finally managed to get internet =]). 1st, I am not sure what you mean by the notation $\omega$, could you expand on that? 2nd, $p$ is just a (single) numeric value. E.g., Let $T$ be fixed to be 3, then we have: $Z_1^{1-p} + Z_2^{1-p} + Z_3^{1-p}=3$, then for each realization of the random variable $Z_t$, i.e., $\{Z_1, Z_2, Z_3\}$, we can solve for a unique $p$. Hence as $Z_t$ changes, $p$ changes. 3rd, $f(p)$ is mandatory in that form, but sure, do what is necessary to get some results first.

Comment: yes thus  $p$ is also a random variable one of the form $p=g(Z_1,Z_2,Z_3)$ with $g$ being some function that solves the corresponding equation ;)

Comment: Ah yup that is correct. Now since $g$ doesn't have a closed-form expression, how can we proceed?

Comment: how good is you background in probability theory ? (if you are asking about $\omega\in\Omega$ which in the context of prob theory almost always denotes an elementary event )

Comment: I know probability theory but not measure-theoretic probability theory.

Comment: Any ideas @Probilitator? :P

Comment: to solve this question properly you should be aware of some measure-theoretic prob. theory ;) still I will see what can be done

Comment: @Probilitator Thank you so much! Any kind of rough working/pointers will be great, I am willing to go learn all the background maths required :)

Comment: could $p$ be a n-dim vector $p=(p_1, \dots, p_n)$ ?

Comment: Since $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are both one-dimensional random variables, $p$ is just one-dimensional.

Comment: Actually I understand your setup so that $X=(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ otherwise it makes no sense adding the $t$ index. If $X_i=X_j \forall j$ the problem would be trivial.